# Where's my mistake evaluating the mass of $V$?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> Evaluate the mass of $V=\{ (x,y,z)|x^2+y^2+z^2\le 2, z \ge 0, x^2+y^2 \ge 1$ }
> While the density of mass is $\phi(x,y,z)=z$

What I did: 
How I visualize $V$: The first part is a ball with a radius $2$ (it's volume), $z\ge 0$ makes me take the upper half of the ball, and for $x^2+y^2 \ge 1$, I drew the cylinder $x^2+y^2=1$ inside the half ball, and $V$ is the volume between the ball and the cylinder. 
So I decided to use ball coordinates to solve: 
$x=r\cos\theta \sin\phi$. 
$y=r\sin\theta \sin\phi.$ 
$z=r\cos\phi$ 
$|J|=r^2\sin\phi$. 
And from how I visualized $V$, I set the bounds as this: 
$1 \le r \le 2$. (from the cylinder to the ball) 
$0\le \phi \le \frac{\pi}{2}$. (from the positive $z$ axis to xy plane - half ball). 
$0 \le \theta \le 2\pi$. (must go around all $V$). 
And so, 
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}d\phi \int_0^{2\pi}d\theta\int_1^2r^3\sin\phi\cos\phi=2\pi[4-\frac{1}{4}]\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin(2\phi)d\phi = \pi[4-\frac{1}{4}]$$
But the final answer is : $\frac{\pi}{4}$.
Would love to know which mistakes I made, thanks in advance.

Comment: With $z$ as integrand, cylindrical coordinates is simpler. Integrating wrt $z$ first, $0 \leq z \leq \sqrt{2-r^2}$ and then $1 \leq r \leq \sqrt2$.

Comment: @MathLover I will definitely try that now! thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lower bound of $\rho$ is incorrect. If you take $\rho = 1$ (a constant), that is a sphere but $\rho$ is bound below by cylinder $x^2+y^2 = 1$ and radial distance to a point on the cylinder is a function of $\phi$

If you are doing this in spherical coordinates, at the surface of the cylinder,

$x^2+y^2 = \rho^2\sin^2\phi = 1 \implies \rho = \csc\phi$

At intersection of sphere and cylinder,

$\rho = \sqrt2, \rho \sin\phi = 1 \implies \phi = \frac{\pi}{4}$

So the integral is,

$\displaystyle \int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2} \int_0^{2\pi} \int_{\csc\phi}^{\sqrt2} \rho^3 \sin\phi \cos\phi \ d\rho \ d\theta \ d\phi = \frac{\pi}{4}$